# Extend expiry on sessions token PHP

Tags: php, html, session, token

I am trying to store sessions in the local storage of the user when they log in, but the expiry of the session is short and it is deleted every time I route to another page, and I could not figure out what had gone wrong. Below is some snippet of my code.

**connect.php**

```php
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "ezcar2";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
?>
```

**ct_home.php**

```php
<body>
<?php
        include_once 'connect.php';
        session_start();

        
        if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
            header("Location: ct_login.php");
            exit();
        } 
    ?>
</body>
```

Whenever I refresh the page, I would be redirected back to `ct_login.php`. I would like for the session to stay until the user logs out.

**EDIT (ct_login.php && setting the sessions)**

```php
<?php
        include_once 'connect.php';
        session_start();
        
        if(isset($_POST['btnlogin'])){
            $c_username = trim($_POST['txtusername']);
            $c_password = trim($_POST['txtpwd']);
            $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM tblcustomer WHERE CT_USERNAME = '$c_username' AND CT_PASSWORD = '$c_password'";
            $sql_role = "SELECT * FROM tblcustomer WHERE CT_USERNAME = '$c_username' AND CT_PASSWORD = '$c_password' AND CT_ROLE = 'CAR OWNER'";
            $sql_status = "SELECT * FROM tblcustomer WHERE CT_USERNAME = '$c_username' AND CT_PASSWORD = '$c_password' AND CT_STATUS = 'APPROVED'";
            
            if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query)){
                $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                if($rows == 1) {
                    if ($status = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_status)) {
                            $row_ = mysqli_num_rows($status);
                                if($row_ == 1) {
                                    if($role = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_role)){
                                     $rows_ = mysqli_num_rows($role);
                                     if($rows_ == 1) {
                                        //store username & password in session variable
                                        $rec = mysqli_fetch_row($role);
                                        $_SESSION['username'] = $rec[7];
                                        $_SESSION['role'] = $rec[9];
                                        header("Location: ct_home.php");
                                        // session_start();
                                } else {
                                        $rec = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
                                        $_SESSION['username'] = $rec[7];
                                        $_SESSION['role'] = $rec[9];
                                        header("Location: ct_home.php");
                                        // session_start();
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo('<script>alert("Account request is still pending. Please wait for confirmation email.");</script>');
                            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
                            exit();
                        }
                    } 
                } else {
                        echo('<script>alert("Invalid Credentials. Please try again!");</script>');
                        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
                        exit();
                        }
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Edit (#1) : The database connection is used to validate user login

Please let me know what else I can provide to draw a clearer picture of the whole situation. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `session_start()` needs to go before any output (even a single space/line break). Also, what does the database connection have to do with your sessions? You also never show how you set the session. As far as we know, you never do.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson changes are made in the original post, the database connection is used to validate user login and create a new user as well as the ```ct_login.php``` file to store sessions

Comment: "trying to store sessions in the local storage". Local storage is a specific thing on the web, do you mean that or are you just using it generically (basically cookies).

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: _**Never ever** ever never_ store passwords in plain text! You should _always_ hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store the hashes. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: This is actually a school assignment, its never going to be into production stage

Comment: @ChrisHaas i am refering to cookies

Comment: Did you try and move the session_start()'s before you output anything as I suggested in my first comment?

Comment: u mean to run session_start() before ```include_once "connect.php"``` ?

Comment: I mean `session_start()` before any _output_. Your include statement doesn't output anything, from what I can see (unless you have some space or line break before `<?php` or after `?>`). But you have `<body>` before it, which means that you have a bunch of output before it.

Comment: so should i put it under <head> ?